# Laravel ShoppingCart issue

Tags: php, laravel, model, composer-php, cart

I need Cart features in my e-commerce site so I decide to use Crinsane. As I read on github docs I run:

```
composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart
```

then add line to `providers` and `aliases` and to test Cart I write:

```
public function addvoucher($id)
    {

       $cart = Cart::add(['id' => '293', 'name' => 'Product 1', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 9.99, 'options' => ['size' => 'large']]);

        return $cart;
    }
```

route off cource:

```
Route::get('/addvoucher/{id}', 'VouchersController@addvoucher');
```

Now when I try to run: localhost:8888/addvoucher/1 I get:

[image]

What is a problem? I do everything like on docs... How to properly install this plugin?

UPDATE:

Now I add in VoucherController just: use Cart;

but now I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Cart in your controller

write:

```
use Cart;
```

in test controller if you add allias for cart in config.

Comment: thanks but now I have: UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 399:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Comment: ALSO I see mogration file in Crinsane code but I dont see that is installed in my database ???

Comment: you run php artisan migrate ?

Comment: create a new migration with content fom package migration. I think this is: https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/blob/master/database/migrations/0000_00_00_000000_create_shoppingcart_table.php

Comment: try php artisan vendor publish